# Does ReSharper/Rider support undefined symbol completion?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, code-completion, rider

By 'undefined symbol completion', I mean the following:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public DataMember X { get; set; } // <-- 'DataMember' symbol not yet defined
}

public class D // <-- typing 'D' should show 'DataMember' in code completion dropdown
```

IntelliJ supports this (facilitating a 'top-down' coding style in accordance with the *step-down rule* as defined in Robert C. Martin's book *Clean Code*).

1. What is 'undefined symbol completion' properly called?
2. Does the ReSharper plugin and/or the Rider IDE support it?

Comment: Why do you want to type the `DataMember` declaration manually? You can hit the `Alt`+`Enter` shortcut on the `DataMember` usage and select "Create type DataMember" in the menu?

Comment: Good question, and ReSharper does in fact provide at least a *few* shortcuts of this nature.

However, these shortcuts are limited in scope, and don't provide maximal control over exactly how undefined symbols are subsequently defined. For example, you may want them in a different order, or you may want to avoid the hassle of navigating context menus using the up/down arrow keys (which leads to RSIs). Often, just typing it out from top to bottom *feels* better.

In general, "Why do you...?" questions are difficult to answer as the contextual possibilities are so broad.